# utn-userfirst-object certificate expiring after 10 Years

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

utn-userfirst-object certificate expiring after 10 years. Anyone know what this certificate is used for?

Certificate information USERTrust

Ensures software came from software publisher
Protects software from alteration after publication
Allows data to be signed with the current time
Allows data on disk to be encrypted
All issuance policies

Sha1RSA

Issued to : UTN-USERFirst-Object
Issued by : UTN-USERFirst-Object

Intended Purpose : Encrypting File System, Time Stamping, Code Signing

Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation, Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing (c6)

Comment: What do you mean by "used for"?

Comment: This Certificate is on all the Windows servers and will soon expire. Dont know what it is used for.if its expires will is impact any windows function?

Comment: I don't think so. Usually, certification authorities stop issuing certificates near the end of their expiration date and the services that depends on these certificate shift to other CAs to keep theirs certificates up to date. Certificate expiration and renovation is a common process in PKI and shouldn't cause trouble if correctly executed by the CAs and certificate owners.